# Add column to dataframe based on operation (min, max, sum) between other columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(
 ("thin", "Cell phone", 6000, 150,  "01/01/2018"),
 ("Normal", "Tablet", 1500, 200, "01/01/2018"),
 ("Mini", "Tablet", 2000, 250, "02/01/2018"),
 ("Ultra thin", "Cell phone", 5000, 300, "02/01/2018"),
 ("Very thin", "Cell phone", 6000, 400, "03/01/2018"),
 ("Big", "Tablet", 4500, 250, "03/01/2018"),
 ("Bendable", "Cell phone", 3000, 200, "04/01/2018"),
 ("Fordable", "Cell phone", 3000, 150, "05/01/2018"),
 ("Pro", "Cell phone", 4500, 300, "06/01/2018"),
 ("Pro2", "Tablet", 6500, 350, "04/01/2018")).toDF("product", "category", 
 "revenue", "extra", "date")
```

I am trying to add a `Column` to this dataframe which contains the an operation based on Columns `revenue` and `extra`. Let´s say a `min` operation so that I get a `Column` such as this:

```
df.withColumn("output", min("revenue", "extra"))
```

The problem I am finding with spark functions, is that these `min`, `max` aggregations are applied vertically, in a `Column`. However, my goal here is to apply these concepts horizontally, across columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use UDF() for that. Check this out.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     |  ("thin", "Cell phone", 6000, 150,  "01/01/2018"),
     |  ("Normal", "Tablet", 1500, 200, "01/01/2018"),
     |  ("Mini", "Tablet", 2000, 250, "02/01/2018"),
     |  ("Ultra thin", "Cell phone", 5000, 300, "02/01/2018"),
     |  ("Very thin", "Cell phone", 6000, 400, "03/01/2018"),
     |  ("Big", "Tablet", 4500, 250, "03/01/2018"),
     |  ("Bendable", "Cell phone", 3000, 200, "04/01/2018"),
     |  ("Fordable", "Cell phone", 3000, 150, "05/01/2018"),
     |  ("Pro", "Cell phone", 4500, 300, "06/01/2018"),
     |  ("Pro2", "Tablet", 6500, 350, "04/01/2018")).toDF("product", "category",
     |  "revenue", "extra", "date")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [product: string, category: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- product: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- revenue: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- extra: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)


scala> def min2col(x:Int,y:Int):Int =
     | return if(x<y) x else y
min2col: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala>  val myudfmin2col = udf( min2col(_:Int,_:Int):Int )
myudfmin2col: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,IntegerType,Some(List(IntegerType, IntegerType)))

scala> df.withColumn("output",myudfmin2col('extra,'revenue)).show(false)
+----------+----------+-------+-----+----------+------+
|product   |category  |revenue|extra|date      |output|
+----------+----------+-------+-----+----------+------+
|thin      |Cell phone|6000   |150  |01/01/2018|150   |
|Normal    |Tablet    |1500   |200  |01/01/2018|200   |
|Mini      |Tablet    |2000   |250  |02/01/2018|250   |
|Ultra thin|Cell phone|5000   |300  |02/01/2018|300   |
|Very thin |Cell phone|6000   |400  |03/01/2018|400   |
|Big       |Tablet    |4500   |250  |03/01/2018|250   |
|Bendable  |Cell phone|3000   |200  |04/01/2018|200   |
|Fordable  |Cell phone|3000   |150  |05/01/2018|150   |
|Pro       |Cell phone|4500   |300  |06/01/2018|300   |
|Pro2      |Tablet    |6500   |350  |04/01/2018|350   |
+----------+----------+-------+-----+----------+------+


scala>
```

**EDIT1:**

```
scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("product")
scala> spark.sql("select product,category,revenue,extra,date, case when revenue<extra then revenue else extra end as minextra  from product ").show(false)
+----------+----------+-------+-----+----------+--------+
|product   |category  |revenue|extra|date      |minextra|
+----------+----------+-------+-----+----------+--------+
|thin      |Cell phone|6000   |150  |01/01/2018|150     |
|Normal    |Tablet    |1500   |200  |01/01/2018|200     |
|Mini      |Tablet    |2000   |250  |02/01/2018|250     |
|Ultra thin|Cell phone|5000   |300  |02/01/2018|300     |
|Very thin |Cell phone|6000   |400  |03/01/2018|400     |
|Big       |Tablet    |4500   |250  |03/01/2018|250     |
|Bendable  |Cell phone|3000   |200  |04/01/2018|200     |
|Fordable  |Cell phone|3000   |150  |05/01/2018|150     |
|Pro       |Cell phone|4500   |300  |06/01/2018|300     |
|Pro2      |Tablet    |6500   |350  |04/01/2018|350     |
+----------+----------+-------+-----+----------+--------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. It´s kind of odd that only udfs are suitable for these cases. Do you know the reason behind it?

Comment: SQL is designed to summarize across rows.. check my EDIT1 for the sql version.

Comment: Okay this sql would work for known columns. But let´s say you need to apply this concept to different dataframes for more than two columns. The only thing we know is a list containing the name of the columns we want to use.

Comment: no other options, you have to customize that with UDF()s.

Comment: Okay, let´ say I can apply this logic by callin `rdd` in my dataframe and then work with `RDD` api, which one would be more advisable to do, UDFs or RDD transformation?

Comment: go with DataFrames and UDFs. RDDs have limitations on the functions. Unless you want to optimize with partitions, don't go for RDD

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/Spark-Definitive-Guide-Matei-Zaharia/dp/935213706X?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=20373f90-f713-467d-8419-73b3d471ae6b is a good place to start Spark